# Peer to peer connection in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

Is there any way such that i can communicate with other android device in the same wifi network... for sharing files.

Can I have list of all android device connected to same n/w?

can any one refer me any api for doing that? or how can I make that thing happen?? this thing must be possible, Isn't it?

I think this is possible in Android 4.0,  using `WiFiDirect`but how that can be possible in lower level sdk's.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at this [WifiP2pManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html)

Comment: yes but WifiP2pManager is only available in 4.0 or plus, I am looking for, lower version of android