# Streaming audio from iPhone to Android in real time over Infrastructural WiFi or Peer to Peer Wifi Network

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, wifi, multipeer-connectivity

We are working on a concept where we need to stream audio from iPhone to Android in real time over Wifi Network basically one device may be iPhone or android can act as a Host and Other Device that too can be a android device or iPhone device which will act as a guest and receives data. 
What we want to know if there exists any api or framework through which we can communicate between two platforms and share the audio data back and fourth.

We tried using Multi-peer framework in iOS platform for iOS to iOS communication. now we want to do cross platform communication.

Please suggest the available ways by which we can do so.

Comment: Hi, Kindly tell me how you did audio streaming between iOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17502818/4038509) question, seems very similar to your needs. Alternatively, look into [AllSeen Alliance framework](https://allseenalliance.org/about) which I believe is your best option as it allows "audio streaming for simultaneous playback on multiple speakers".